# Character set troubles

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

How to change the character set of a mysql database after setting it to the wrong character set.
In fact, i'm having some problems for printing special characters pulled from a mysql database.
It is a php programming language.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you could be doing wrong.  Please study the 'best practices' in [*here*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

If that does not suffice, perhaps the it can help with "problems printing".

If still not sufficient, show us the connection, set_charset, `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, sample printout, and sample of text that is giving trouble.

Comment: Although the link you provided contains some useful infos but it's not what i'm actually looking for.

Comment: It covers "Black Diamonds", which you have.  However, there are two sub-cases, read the discussion and let us know which you have.

Comment: Also, without `SELECT HEX(...) ...`, we can't be really sure what is in the table.